# jFreechart points vanish when clicking

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a Java 6/Swing application (yes, I know, but thats the requirement) and I need to show some polar plots. Everything works so far so good, but when I click on the plot, the plotted points vanish, even if I move the window around it might vanish.
I work with netbeans, here is a dummy-code that causes the same issue

The libraries used are

- jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
- jcommon-1.0.23.jar

**NewJFrame.java**

```
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    private PlotHandler plotHandler;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        plotHandler = new PlotHandler(jPanel1, "blub", 1);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 504, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 409, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(217, 217, 217))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        XYSeriesCollection data;
        XYSeries series;//("Bearing"+getBearingIndex(i));
        data = new XYSeriesCollection();
        series = new XYSeries("Bearings");
        series.add(Math.random()*180/Math.PI, 
            Math.random());
        data.addSeries(series);
        plotHandler.plotData(data);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**PlotHandler.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class PlotHandler {
    private final JPanel jPanel;
    private final String plane;
    private double range;


    public PlotHandler(JPanel jPanel, String plane, double range) {
        this.jPanel = jPanel;
        this.plane = plane;
        this.range = range;

        // initialize plot
        this.jPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        this.jPanel.add(PolarPlotHandler.emptyPolarChart(range), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.jPanel.validate();
    }

    public void plotData(XYSeriesCollection data) {
        jPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jPanel.add(PolarPlotHandler.createPolarChart(data, range), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jPanel.validate();        
    }
}
```

**PolarPlotHandler.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.PolarChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PolarPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.DefaultPolarItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public final class PolarPlotHandler  {

    private PolarPlotHandler() {  } 

    public static ChartPanel createPolarChart(XYSeriesCollection data, double range) {
        final XYDataset dataset = data;
        range = 200;
        range = Math.ceil(range/10)*10;
        range = Math.max(1, range);
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, range/1000000);
        if(data.getSeriesCount()<=1 && data.getSeries(0).getItemCount()>0)
            chart.removeLegend();
        else {

        }
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new PolarChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(false);
        chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(false);

        return chartPanel;
    }
    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset, double range) {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPolarChart(
                "", dataset, true, true, false
        );
        final PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
        // get Axis
        plot.setAngleOffset(0);
        plot.setCounterClockwise(true);
        plot.getAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        plot.setAngleTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(45));
        ((NumberAxis)plot.getAxis()).setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(range));
        // find the maximum range
        plot.getAxis().setRange(0, 2.0);
        plot.getAxis().setVisible(true);
        plot.setBackgroundAlpha(0.0f);
        plot.setAngleGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setRadiusGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        final DefaultPolarItemRenderer renderer = (DefaultPolarItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesFilled(2, false);
        return chart;
    }
public static ChartPanel emptyPolarChart() {
    return emptyPolarChart(200.0);
}

public static ChartPanel emptyPolarChart(double range) {
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(new XYSeriesCollection(), range/1000000);
    chart.removeLegend();
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new PolarChartPanel(chart);
    return chartPanel;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to update a `PolarPlot` by replacing the entire, enclosing `ChartPanel`. Instead, update the dataset's series and the listening chart panel will update itself in response. In the example below, the button's handler clears the dataset's `XYSeries` and adds a new, random point each time the button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    series.clear();
    series.add(r.nextDouble() * 360, r.nextDouble());
}
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PolarPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36846122/230513 */
public class Test {

    private final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series");
    private final XYDataset dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    public Test() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPolarChart(
            "Title", dataset, true, true, false);
        final PolarPlot plot = (PolarPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        plot.getAxis().setRange(0, 1);
        plot.getAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        plot.setAngleGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setRadiusGridlinePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setRadiusMinorGridlinesVisible(false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            Random r = new Random();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                series.clear();
                series.add(r.nextDouble() * 360, r.nextDouble());
            }
        });
        JPanel control = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        control.add(button);

        f.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test t = new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works as well. I just found another solution: add `jPanel.removeAll()`. The problem was, that I always added new charts to the panel without removing the existing ones. Nevertheless, I think updating the dataset is more elegant.

Comment: I think this is more scalable; user `ChartPanel::setChart()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+setchart), if needed.